# How to upgrade from Expressmapper to Automapper?

Tags: c#, automapper

We're using Expressmapper in our C# Web API, but it's not being maintained actively, e.g. it's still not compatible with .NET Core.
So I want to upgrade to Automapper. 
Is there any guide how to upgrade our code?

As I map a JSON object to our DTO objects, I don't have control over the source, and I do a lot of "for member X in source do this an map to member Y in destination".

Comment: Do you have any more concrete examples of the code you had in ExpressMapper? I'm not sure there's many people in the world that have tried this migration.

Comment: Yeah thought so. Luckily EM is now compatible with .NET Core, so we don't have to migrate!

Comment: Nice! The best code is the code you don't have to write